# Storing a a lists new order in a suitable way

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery ui's sortable. A list of objects is retrieved from the db an dynamically put into a list, the user drag and drops the list objects and the new order of the list should get saved.

Below is the jQuery code for sortable, which include creating an array of the new list order. However, next step is to do something so that I'm able to use this array in my php code.

The thing is that the user, apart from sorting the list objects also should be able to add some comments and do some other stuff and then submit it all. That is, I'm using a form for this. By that reason I must be able to put in the array with the list order into the form in some way, and here's where I need some help.

What method should I use? Ajax? Local storage? How could this be accomplished?

```
    $('#listElements').sortable({

        update: function(event, ui) {
            var order = []; 
            $('.listObject li').each( function(e) {
                order.push($(this).attr('id'));
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use AJAX to send the order array to PHP like so:

```
$('#listElements').sortable({
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var order = [];
        $('.listObject li').each(function (e) {
            order.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/save_order_to_db",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                order_data: order
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very conversant with AJAX but will give it a try. How could I retrieve this data on the page? I want the list order array to be used in the form, i.e. not open up another page etc.

Comment: You can use a `success` callback to retrieve the data. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do I retrieve the data in my php code with the help of the success callback you mean, and should the url be the same url as the page with the list and the form?

Comment: The url should be the PHP page that saves the order array to the DB.